# How to integrate Unity inside native iOS App?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm having troubles integrating a simple Unity project inside a native iOS App.

I followed this [this](http://www.the-nerd.be/2014/09/08/sandbox-unity-app-in-existing-ios-app/) tutorial but I think that some things have changed since it was written. I'm stuck with this error:

[image: error]

And thats not the only one, there are 1600 files that include include that file. The problem is that all this 1600 files have a wrong reference to il2cpp-codegen.h

[image: files]

This are my build settings for the Unity project:

[image]

So, after following all the tutorial, should I change all the files so that all the references would be correct? Or am I missing something else?

Thanks!

Joel

**EDIT**
I'm currently using Unity 5.1.1f1 Personal version.

Comment: No, I wouldn't run through and change all the files. There's something else wrong, I think. But I don't know enough about it to say what. I do know that occasionally Xcode updates break Unity's iPhone building process, and they have to fix it.

Comment: I have fixed and create a repository with tutorial and downloadable project. But i have write a answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714106/integrate-unity-app-to-existing-ios-app/40432425#40432425

Comment: @Joel I'm getting this error "il2cpp-config.h' file not found" how to fix this .Please help me out

Comment: Did anyone find any solution for same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a warning saying folder not found or something like it?
I think you didn't set the path for Libraries/libil2cpp/include in your header search paths.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't copy the `Libraries/libil2cpp` folder.

That folder isn't visible inside the Xcode project but you can find it in `Finder`. You should try and copy that folder also and maybe add it to the `Build Phases` in Xcode. Not sure about this last step.