# Integrate unity app to existing iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unity-game-engine

I have an iOS app export from Unity 5 and also I used vuforia to add ar to that Unity app. Now I want to integrate the Unity app to my existing iOS app.

I have followed http://www.the-nerd.be/2015/11/13/integrate-unity-5-in-a-native-ios-app-with-xcode-7/#comment-446 tutorial and this is good for integrating Unity without Vuforia.

So how can i do this and also its better to do this using swift

Comment: Thank u @Krypton. But there is no any answer for my question :P

Answer (score 4):

i made a integration with **Unity 5.3.8p8** and **Vuforia 6.0.117** for **iOS 8.4 and up**.
These tutorial is made for Objective-C, but you can do for Swift with no problem, just create a PREFIX HEADER and import all .h files there and substitute for the right code in my example bellow.

After you export you Unity project for XCode, open it and create a Group Folder.
Inside that folder you created, create a .mm file with the name you want ( mine is mainAppController.mm ), there is:

```
// mainAppController.mm
//
// Import this default headers to make Unity and Vuforia works
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UnityAppController.h"
#import "UI/UnityView.h"
#import "UI/UnityViewControllerBase.h"
#import "VuforiaRenderDelegate.h"

// This is your MAIN VIEWCONTROLLER, that controller you want to open first when build/open your app.
#import "MainViewController.h"



// Unity native rendering callback plugin mechanism is only supported
// from version 4.5 onwards
#if UNITY_VERSION>434
// Exported methods for native rendering callback
extern "C" void UnitySetGraphicsDevice(void* device, int deviceType, int eventType);
extern "C" void UnityRenderEvent(int marker);

// This is for Vuforia Render Delegate, i copy it from VuforiaNativeRenderController.mm and add here to make it work

extern "C" void VuforiaSetGraphicsDevice(void* device, int deviceType, int eventType);
extern "C" void VuforiaRenderEvent(int marker);

#endif

@interface mainAppController : UnityAppController<UIApplicationDelegate>

// My historyboard works with NavigationController.
// If your app doenst use navigation, just open the historiboard with your main ViewController.

@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;

- (void)willStartWithViewController:(UIViewController*)controller;
- (void)shouldAttachRenderDelegate;

@end



@implementation mainAppController


- (void)shouldAttachRenderDelegate
{

    self.renderDelegate = [[VuforiaRenderDelegate alloc] init];
    // Unity native rendering callback plugin mechanism is only supported
    // from version 4.5 onwards
#if UNITY_VERSION>434
    //
    // I comment this line bellow because Vuforia hendle it, and you see what will work with Vuforia.
    //
    //UnityRegisterRenderingPlugin(&UnitySetGraphicsDevice, &UnityRenderEvent);
    UnityRegisterRenderingPlugin(&VuforiaSetGraphicsDevice, &VuforiaRenderEvent);
#endif

}


- (void)willStartWithViewController:(UIViewController*)controller {

    //
    // Open your historyboard with your main view.
   // In my case i use navigation controller.

    UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
    storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    _rootController         = [[UnityDefaultViewController alloc] init];
    _rootView               = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    _rootController.view    = _rootView;

    MainViewController *mainVC       = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"idMainViewController"];

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];

    [_rootView addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
}

@end


//
// You have to put this line below and comment out the equal line below in file VuforiaNativeRenderController.mm
//
IMPL_APP_CONTROLLER_SUBCLASS(mainAppController)
```

You notice that i'm using Storyboard.
So my MainViewController is the ViewController root of the Navigation Controller. Right!
Inside my MainViewController, i do this:

```
//  MainViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UnityAppController.h"
#import "UI/UnityView.h"
#import "UI/UnityViewControllerBase.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
{
    UnityDefaultViewController *unityViewController;
    UnityAppController *unityController;
}

-(IBAction) touchToLoad:(id)sender;

@end
```

```
//  MainViewController.m
//
// This is just a EXAMPLE FILE, that i use in my project.
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "ARViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // My project use navigation controller just for transition animation right to left, thats why i hide it here on first view.

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
//- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
//{
//    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"idHomeViewController"])
//    {
////        MyViewController *controller = (MyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
////        controller.myProperty1 = ...;
////        controller.myProperty2 = ...;
//    }
//    
//    
//}


-(void)touchToLoad:(id)sender
{
    //
    // Open historyboard with Unity and Vuforia, see details on ARViewController.h/m

    UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
    storyBoard                      = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ARViewController *mainVC        = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"idARViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainVC animated:YES];
}

@end
```

For better knowledge, i put a button to go to Unity View inside my storyboard. So that way i can handle the native UI from xcode.
Then i have the ARViewController that show Unity and Vuforia working.

```
//  ARViewController.h
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UnityAppController.h"
#import "UI/UnityView.h"
#import "UI/UnityViewControllerBase.h"


@interface ARViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIView     *viewToUnity;
    UnityDefaultViewController *unityViewController;
    UnityAppController *unityController;
}

-(IBAction) goBack:(id)sender;

@end
```

```
//  ARViewController.m
//
//

#import "ARViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ARViewController ()

@end

@implementation ARViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Just setting Unity delegates and view to add it as subview for my main view.
    // This allow me to add a UIButton above the UnityView to popViewController or anything i want to make native in iOS.

    unityViewController         = [[UnityDefaultViewController alloc] init];
    unityController             = (UnityAppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    unityViewController.view    = (UIView*)unityController.unityView;

    [viewToUnity addSubview:unityViewController.view];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

#pragma MARK -- Methods
-(void)goBack:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

I made a repo for download a project working.
https://bitbucket.org/jack_loverde/unity-5-vuforia-6-and-ios-native-integration in case you want to test this version working.

Hope it help you.

Thanks

Comment: This code can't be compiled due to "Expected identifier or '('" on the Lines starting with "extern "C" void". How did you solved it?

Comment: What is your Unity and Vuforia version?

Comment: We use Unity in most recent version 2017.3.03f that comes shipped with Vuforia (what is the case since Unity 2017.2: https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/getting-started-with-vuforia-in-unity-2017-2-beta.html)

Comment: Sorry man, this version I have not worked yet. If this error is because you opened my project in this latest version of Unity, that's probably why the bugs are. Since, many things change in Unity and Vuforia, you better open my XCode and compare with your XCode and adapt the things you need. Thanks for your message!